# Maximum possible magnification with glass lenses

Tags: optics, lenses

What kind of magnification function does stacking lenses produce? Is the magnification factor a multiplicative, additive or a different function? For example, does stacking two concave lenses with magnification factors A and B produce magnification factor C=A+B or C=A*B or C=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this page:

http://www.livephysics.com/problems-and-answers/optics/lens-system-image-distance-magnification/

At the end is said that total magnification is the product of A and B.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.